# 100% input width that stretches fluidly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is more complicated than it should be, but I'm having trouble displaying an input width of literally 100% of within its div.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aml90/mfdtk/

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. I want the inputs to be 100% of the width of the `span6` classes, like the blue highlights:

[image]

Despite the lack of CSS, I have tried many things -- just didn't put the non-working CSS on there.

You will need to resize the windows, like this:

[image: Window resize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it have to be something like this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mfdtk/1/)

```
.input-prepend{
    width:100%;
}
.input-prepend input{
    width:95%;
}
```

Comment: Very simple and it works without having to adjust other things.

Comment: Exceeding a certain width, the inputs will arrange themselves side by side again. You can see that in the jsfiddle. It works, as long as the parent doesn't get too wide, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
.span6 .input-prepend {
     padding-left:28px;
     display:block;
}
.span6 .input-prepend .add-on {
     float:left;
     margin-left:-28px;
}
.span6 .input-prepend input {
     width:100% !important;
}
```

this will put the add-on to the left side, and let the input take up remaining space

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfdtk/2/)

Comment: I am aware of this. As I stated several times in the post, I want the inputs' widths to be 100% of the span6's. And they are not -- only 50% of the span6, even though I added width:100% to the inputs.

Comment: Updated answer it should stretch as needed.

Comment: I accepted another answer but I +1'd for the help and effort ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Patching Bootstrap in such a way is a bit tricky, since there can be different "side effects". Maybe something along those lines will do the trick for you:

```
.span6 { width: 100% !important; margin-left: 0 !important }
.span6 input { width: 92%; }
.input-prepend { display: block; }
```

Play around with overriding these CSS directives and test you layout with it. Good luck!
http://jsfiddle.net/Yuv3H/